# PyQt Common Scientific Software Pattern: Tree and Settings Box

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm not thinking about this in the correct way, and maybe the resources are already out there but I cannot seem to find the right terminology to read about its implementation.

Many software packages have arbitrarily complex data objects who's relationship is shown in "tree" form, and when you click any of the items then another widget displays the various settings and editing widgets, and then usually there's also a visualization pane.

I tried to make a sample here:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

The problem is that whenever I try to implement this my thing becomes a mess. I was thinking that for every property perhaps I would `setData` and insert a model in there, and recall it and set it to the settings-view whenever an item is clicked, but that's meant for QVariants only and when I put a C++ object in there the application segfaults.

The idea of making individual setting boxes for every type of item seems tedious and inelegant. What I really want is that whenever I click on an item in the tree, the item somehow contains a dict of simple data-types (str, int, float, path) that behaves like a model that the user interacts with via the Item Settings "Table View", with appropriate delegates for each item type.

What is the name of this pattern? Where can I learn how to implement it with Qt?

Comment: Could you make a more complex picture mockup? As in show what you expect to be shown in the two empty widgets you have.

Comment: I added a picture, but here is some further explanation. Imagine that each top level item is a Family. Whenever you click on the family name, or on any of its children or children's children, the void space on the right could, say, display a picture of the family.


Meanwhile, the bottom box, upon any item being selected, would display some information internal to the object- NOT visible in the tree-view, that is nontheless an attribute of the object and editable with appropriate delegates.


The thing that comes to mind is a hybrid Python/QModel object, but there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for seems to be the `QDataWidgetMapper`! The last part of this tutorial covers it well. The tutorial is overall perfect for learning to produce precisely this kind of application.

http://www.yasinuludag.com/blog/?p=98

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what the question is but I'll take a chance: I see the tree and the properties panel as being two different views of the same model. The model is a hierarchy of elements with the leaf nodes (and even non-leaf nodes) having certain properties that can be edited. The tree view is a view of the hierarchy, that's all it does, is allow to browse the hierarchy by showing it, allow perhaps to expand & collapse branches, filter, etc. The properties view is a view of one node, the node that is currently selected in tree.

So the tree view represents the hierarchy part of the model, and when user selects a node, emits a signal informing what node was selected. The other view is connected to this signal, and fetches the properties of selected node and displays them. If the properties contain enough meta-data then the properties view can create on the fly the correct controls for each property: range properties with min-max represented as a text field with two arrows, one-of properties as a combo box, etc. You would probably create a table of two columns: left column is property names for selected node, and right column contains the widgets for interacting with each property. You would have a different type of widget for each property type, your table creator would instantiate the correct type of widget on this basis.

I don't see why you would need more than one model.

For tree, QTreeView. For properties, QTableView. Or, QtPropertyBrowser might do the trick, but doesn't seem to be available in pyqt, maybe this can be clue to find something similar.

Comment: I'm terrible at asking questions in SO- what I usually want is not some code-fix but some conceptual understanding.

This is actually quite good, and what I had in mind. What I'm not sure about is what Qt structures I should be using. Would one single model suffice? And then the properties view wouldn't be a table view, but a different kind of single-item view? I'm lost as to which widgets to use.

Comment: I just can't seem to extend the StandardItemModel to do this. I thought that maybe the hierarchy can display only column 0, and the properties view can display columns 1: of the selected row only, transposed... but it just seems so convoluted. Also, "children" in the tree obviously don't readily display on the table.